# renaming file name and mask with unknown file format.

Tags: linux, shell, sed, find

I have files mask below. with a very complicated file names.
An example is show below. The unique identifier for the files is the number 0003915. I need to rename the file from

> From 'journal.pks.0003915&representation=PDF'  to 'journal.pks.0003915.pdf'

However the most intresting thing is that I have about 5000 files in folders and subfolders. And I dont know these numbers. I know that there is a range of files from 0000001 to 0003915. What is show below is an example. The file mask is '0003915&representation=PDF' I am looking for a way to modify the code below to do the Job.

> journal.pks.0003915&representation=PDF

```
#!/bin/bash
 for file in $(find /tmp -name '*.txt')
  do
   mv $file $(echo "$file" | sed -r 's|.txt|.cpp|g')
 done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
date > 2PDF.log
for File in $(find /tmp -name '*PDF' -print)
 do
   mv "${File}" "${File%\&*}.pdf"
   echo "${File} -> ${File%\&*}.pdf" >> 2PDF.log
 done
```

using shell feature and a bit of log in case things goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work. We can extract the part you want as the new name and then move the file with that:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in $(ls)
do
    newName=$(echo $f | cut -d\' -f2)
    newName="$newName.cpp"
    mv $f $newName
done
```